# Mount (Volumes) not working when embedding Kafka connect into Ksqldb-server

Tags: docker, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, ksqldb

The "volumes" mapping does not seem to work when trying to embed Kafka connector in Ksqldb Server

Below is my docker file

```
ksqldb-server:
        image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.18.0
        hostname: ksqldb-server
        container_name: ksqldb-server
        depends_on:
          - broker
          - schema-registry
        ports:
          - "8088:8088"
        volumes:
          - "/usr/local/share/kafka/connectors/debezium-debezium-connector-mysql/lib:/usr/share/kafka/plugins/"
        environment:
          KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
          KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:9092"
          KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
          KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
          KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
          # Configuration to embed Kafka Connect support.
          KSQL_CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "ksql-connect-cluster"
          KSQL_CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:9092"
          KSQL_CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
          KSQL_CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
          KSQL_CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
          KSQL_CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: "_ksql-connect-configs"
          KSQL_CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: "_ksql-connect-offsets"
          KSQL_CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: "_ksql-connect-statuses"
          KSQL_CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          KSQL_CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          KSQL_CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          KSQL_CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/kafka/plugins"
```

I see the below error when I am trying to create a source using the connector

**{
"error_code" : 500,
"message" : "Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector, available connectors are: ..........}"
}**

I do have the required jar files installed locally in the folder "/usr/local/share/kafka/connectors/debezium-debezium-connector-mysql/lib" as mapped in the volumes in the docker file above.

What is it that I am missing?

Much appreciated

Comment: Does it work with the non-embedded Connect server?

Comment: Also, the mounts work fine. The plugin scanner/path config might be incorrect, and you should see logs that say what plugins are scanned as the container starts

Comment: Can you share "ls -a" of your user mount?

Comment: "ls -a" results in the below -  
.         
..                              
 antlr4-runtime-4.7.2.jar                
 debezium-connector-mysql-1.1.0.Final.jar 
debezium-ddl-parser-1.1.0.Final.jar      
mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar                                    
debezium-api-1.1.0.Final.jar             
debezium-core-1.1.0.Final.jar            
mysql-binlog-connector-java-0.19.1.jar

Comment: It works with non-embedded Connect server.  I can log into the docker container and navigate the folders. (docker exec -it  ksqldb-server bash). 

I am unable to find the file that has the link to the plugin folders.  connect-distributed.properties seems missing in the ksqldb-server container.

Comment: Ksqldb does not use connect-distributed as its propeties file

Comment: It uses ksql-server.properties

Comment: The connect.properties files is in /etc/ksqldb folder inside the docker container.  The path to plugins is as follows - what I have in the docker file
plugin.path=/usr/share/kafka/plugins.  So this part seems to be right in the docker file.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading a connector zip file extract their files into the plugin path in your worker configuration (e.g. connect-distributed.properties) using the plugin.path configuration property. As an example, let’s assume you have downloaded the Debezium MySQL connector archive and extracted its contents to /kafka/connect/debezium-connector-mysql. Then you’d specify the following in the worker config:

plugin.path=/kafka/connect

So in your case you mounting to an inner path, the connector plugin needs to be inside another folder and not directly the plugin path mount

Comment: I tried the below - still seem to get the same error.               

volumes:
          - "/usr/local/share/kafka/connectors/:/usr/share/kafka/plugins/"

Comment: It seems like your jars are inside lib, and directory not called debezium-connector-mysql-1.6.0.Final-plugin, try to download the connector again , remove other files from the directory and just extract it there

Comment: Keep the directory tree as it is in tar file , do not change anything

Comment: I re-installed the plugin and changed the docker compose file to back it was.  I still see the same error. 

volumes:
          - "/usr/local/share/kafka/connectors/debezium-debezium-connector-mysql/lib/:/usr/share/kafka/plugins/"

Also realised - the connect.properties is generated based on the environment variables specified in the docker compose file.  So this line => KSQL_CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/kafka/plugins" is where we are asking KsqlDB server to look for connector and in volumes mapping it to files on the local machine running docker.

Comment: It is not what I advised you to do...there are clear instructions in debezium site on how to install the connectors, try following along

Comment: I am trying to "embed" Kafka Connect support into KSQLDB server, so that I can create materialized cache.  So even if I take off the debezium connector, I run into the same problem if I use other connectors.  So my problem is specific to the docker mount/mapping and not related to debezium.

Answer (score 0):

The below mapping worked for me

```
volumes:
          - "./confluent-hub-components/:/usr/share/kafka/plugins/"
```

The possible answer is - for the folder "/usr/local/share/kafka/connectors/" perhaps, there is a permission related issue and hence the mapping was not working in the docker compose file.  With the new folder as above (which is not in /usr root folder), mapping works.